# Typescript, define a generic instead object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Currently I have this interfaces:

```
export interface requestPayload {
  agentId: string;
}

export interface Agent {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  requestPayload: requestPayload;
}
```

My problem is `requestPayload` property of `Agent` interface is now an object with `{ agentId: string; }`

But `requestPayload` should be anything, like an array, number, string, and maybe that object that I defined with `requestPayload` interface.

I got a suggestion to "use a generic", how can I change that to a generic? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why make a `requestPayload` interface in the first place if `requestPayload` doesn't have to match the type?

Comment: At first I thought that `requestPayload` would be always an object, but now it seems that can be anything, so how can define it's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generics is quite right solution for your case:

```
export interface Agent<T> {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  requestPayload: T;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was posting that as a solution because I wasn't sure if it was correct

Comment: Depends on your tasks and goals. If you wish to shape every instance of `Agent` that this solution is for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unknown`:

```
export interface Agent {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  requestPayload: unknown;
}
```

As the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#unknown) indicate, it was meant for this sort of thing.

Comment: That's a solution but I can't, the Eslint config for this project doesn't allow `any` types.

Comment: Ok, with `unknown` I have other eslint problems, when I want to acces a propery of an object it says that it's not possible on `unknown` type